# Ruby on rails - Devise - Integration Testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, post, devise

I am trying to test my sign up page but I don't understand why it doesn't work.

```
   #SIGN UP FLOWS
    test "signed up user with valid info is redirected to root" do
     get root_path

     post user_registration_path, :user_email => "asasas@as.com", :user_password =>  "asasas", :user_password_confirmation =>  "asasas"
     follow_redirect!
     assert_equal "/", path
    end
```

I have also tried :

```
   #SIGN UP FLOWS
    test "signed up user with valid info is redirected to posts" do
     get root_path
     @david = User.create(email: "aaaasadasadaddamdaaa@aaa.com", password: Devise::Encryptor.digest(User, "aaaaaa"))
     post user_registration_path, 'user[email]' => @david.email, 'user[password]' =>  @david.password, 'user[password_confirmation]' =>  @david.password

     assert_equal "/", path
   end
```

Instead of going to my root which is `/` It stays on the same page. I tried to do `follow_redirect!` but it gives me the error that reduction is not possible because `RuntimeError: not a redirect! 200 OK`.

What am I doing wrong? I have looked at devise GitHub page but there is no information about registration testing.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it at all? Put a breakpoint in your code, and try executing each command. Try running the steps manually. If you have written any custom controller code, try putting breakpoints in there, to see what happens.

Comment: A few possible issues that I would **guess** could be causing problems are: (1) Why are you doing: `password: Devise::Encryptor.digest(User, "aaaaaa")`? You can just do `password: "aaaaa"`. You're setting the password here, not the encrypted password! (2) Does accessing `@david.password` actually work, after creating the record? I'm not sure. I suspect this virtual attribute may get reset to `nil`. (3) Do you have any additional requirements to log in, e.g. a password format policy or the need to be `confirmed_at`?

Comment: Oh, and in fact -- I just realised: With your second approach, **why are you creating the user, THEN sending `post user_registration_path`**?? That's clearly not going to work... The user cannot already exist before they register!

Comment: I guess to summarise this rambling, I would say: What do you *expect* to happen here? What does your application actually *do*? For example, it's quite common to send a confirmation email before the user can actually log in.

Comment: Thank you for the issues you have pointed out. I am 
     post user_registration_path, 'user[email]' => "sisisissadis@gmail.com", 'user[password]' =>  "aaaaaaaa", 'user[password_confirmation]' =>  "aaaaaaaa"

This is what i am doing right now and it passes the test when in fact it shouldn't because one user cannot sign up with the same email address more than once. 
What do you expect to happen here? I expect the user to be added to database
@TomLord

Comment: *"it passes the test when in fact it shouldn't because one user cannot sign up with the same email address more than once"* -- You never tested that the user cannot sign up twice. You only tested `assert_equal "/", path`.

Comment: *"I expect the user to be added to database"* -- You never tested that the user is added to the database. Again, you only tested `assert_equal "/", path`.

Comment: Also, I thought those were two attempts at performing the same test; but now you say they are two separate scenarios. (Which makes more sense, since they *are* separate scenarios!) But in that case, you should obviously be running some different assertion.